# PHP error. Why is "variable undefined" inside array_map?

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I am using `array_map` function in my php application. 
I defined the array_map function like this.

```
$ratingID =  $this->db->insert_id();

    $rated_item_array = array_map(function ($a) {
        return $a + array('RatingID' => $ratingID);
    }, $rated_item_array);
```

Php notice comes

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: ratingID
```

When i print the `$ratingID` . i prints the value correctly , so $ratingID is defined.
Why it is undfined in `array_map` function?
    My `$rated_item_array` is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 1,
            [PreferenceID] => 45,
            [RatedValue] => 1,
            [CreatedOn] => 1326790338,
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 2,
            [PreferenceID] => 45,
            [RatedValue] => 1,
            [CreatedOn] => 1326790338,
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 3,
            [PreferenceID] => 45,
            [RatedValue] => 1,
            [CreatedOn] => 1326790338,
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )
)
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
$rated_item_array = array_map(
  function ($a) use ($ratingID){ 
    return $a + array('RatingID' => $ratingID ); 
  }, 
  $rated_item_array
);
```

Comment: From php.net documentation on anonymous functions. "Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct." Look at example #3 http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php